# Table view cell text overlaps others when tapped multiple times

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiwebview

I created a list of Youtube videos but there are some problems:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSString *url = [selectedCellItem.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIWebView *wbView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, ROW_HEIGHT, ROW_HEIGHT)];
    wbView.tag = 1;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:wbView];
    [wbView release];

    NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML,url, ROW_HEIGHT, ROW_HEIGHT];
    UIWebView *thisVideoView = (UIWebView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];  
    thisVideoView.delegate = self;
    [thisVideoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

    CGFloat cellWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-ROW_HEIGHT-5;
    NSString *cellValue = [selectedCellItem.title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(ROW_HEIGHT+5, 0.0, cellWidth, ROW_HEIGHT);
    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];

    titleLabel.tag = 2;
    titleLabel.text = cellValue;
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    [titleLabel setNumberOfLines:10];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];
    [titleLabel release];

    return cell;
}
```

At the beginning, my app works just fine. However, when I click one cell multiple times the label starts overlapping with other cell labels. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: If the problem is solved, you should check your question as solved and choose an answer to help people in the future with the same problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because you're creating the titleLabel everytime the function is called. Keep in mind that cell are re-used when table view is scrolled, so basically everytime a cell is used you're re-creating the titleLabel without removing the old one

Comment: thanks for the reply. but what should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: I would move the creation of *titleLabel in the if (cell == nil) block. In this way, you're creating it just when needed. And later you can retrieve it by the tag you're assigning it :)

Comment: I've tried this but...now the entire order of items become chaotic...and pretty random .. each time I scroll the tableview it return different labels...what's wrong? or should I only move UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame]; 
 
into the if block?

Comment: If you move NSString *cellValue = [selectedCellItem.title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; in the if, it's normal that everything mix up, because you're assigning the content of the cell ONLY when you need to create it. I would only move UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame]; into the if block

Comment: Seriously, this is going to be mark as an "unresolved" question if you don't mark it as solved :(

Answer (score 2):

Try to set `cell.clipsToBounds = YES`.